# accessing hard drive data with Microsoft basic data

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount

I had a NAS (buffalo wvl) with two hard drives in it. The NAS has just gone belly up. So I bought a new one - Synology 216j. However, I found out that 216j wipes everything that's added to it before it can be used. So I mounted the 2 hard drive into my Linux desktop and try to read the data and transfer to the new NAS via samba or ftp.

When I installed the HD in the desktop and booted up, `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` shows a list of 6 partitions all with type `Microsoft basic data`. But the first partition `sdb1` was mounted as `ext3` by an existing line in `/etc/fstab`. It looks like the system think that the hard drive was configured to be RAID some how. I don't remember doing that as I remember they were mounted separately as `/mnt/disk{1,2}` in the NAS.

How could I read the data from those drives? I have over 2TB of data I'd like to keep.

Comment: *I don't remember doing that as I remember they were mounted separately as /mnt/disk{1,2} in the NAS.* - That is because it implemented RAID 0 behind the scenes.